# Issue with click eventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found an example task to display an alert on a page when you click anywhere in a document. In the task you need to edit only the display() function, which has two parameters - myFunc and myObj, so that the name of the person object is displayed. I've come up with something like this, but the alert only comes up after the page refreshes, not after each click on the document.

```
function start() {
    var person = {
        name : "John"
    };
    function alertName() {
        alert(""+this.name.toUpperCase() + "");
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', display(alertName, person));
}
function display(myFunc, myObj) {
  name = myObj.name;
  myFunc();

}
start();
```

here is fiddle:

```js
function start() {
    var person = {
        name : "John"
    };
    function alertName() {
        alert(""+this.name.toUpperCase() + "");
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', start(alertName, person));
}
function display(myFunc, myObj) {
  name = myObj.name;
  myFunc();

}
start();
```

```css
body {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
  <body>

  </body>
```

Comment: that's not how an event listener works. You don't get to choose the parameters in the callback. Plus, doing it that way executes the function _at the time you declare the event listener_, due to the inclusion of the arguments. You need to pass a _reference to a function_. What you're doing technically is passing the _result of the display() function_ as the callback argument. Which makes no sense, because that function doesn't return anything. And your fiddle doesn't work because you call a function that doesn't exist and it doesn't match the sample here. Check your stuff before posting :-)

Comment: No jquery in there - did you intend to use jquery or javascript alone?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here in that addEventListener second parameter need to be the function you want to invoke when the event is trigger.

In your exemple, you passed an instruction and not a function. What you can do is add the display() call inside a function body, and pass that function as the second parameter :

```
function start() {
    var person = {
        name : "John"
    };
    function alertName() {
        alert(""+this.name.toUpperCase() + "");
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    display(alertName, person)
    });
}
function display(myFunc, myObj) {
  name = myObj.name;
  myFunc();

}
start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `display` is a function and by `display(alertName, person)` you are calling it immediately, not as a event callback. However `addEventListener` needs function reference as the second parameter so it means that when called `display(alertName, person)` must return a new function that will call `alertName` (which is a reference) from inside.

Finally, `this.name` inside `alertName` implies that it needs to be invoked in context of `myObj`, use [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to do it.

```js
function start() {
  var person = {        
    name: "John"    
  }
  
  function alertName() {        
    alert("" + this.name.toUpperCase() + "");    
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('click', display(alertName, person));
}

function display(myFunc, myObj) {
  return function () {
    myFunc.call(myObj)
  }
}
start();
```

```html
Click somewhere.
```